Divergence and rotational calculation for cylindrical coordinates with tensor calculus
Hi I'm asked to use the following relations (which I have demostrated before) in order to calculate div and rot in cylindrical coordinates: (where X is a vector field)
$$div X = (-1)^{d-1}\nabla_\gamma X^\gamma \quad \quad rot(X)_i=\sqrt(g)\epsilon({1\alpha\beta})\nabla^\alpha X^\beta$$
Using cylindrical coordinates metric for the divergence I obtain the following result ${1,2,3}={r,\phi,z}$:
$$div X=\partial_1 X^1 + X^1/r + \partial_2 X^2+\partial_3 X^3$$
But it seems that it should be $\partial_2 X^2/r$ according to cylindrical divergence where can I have miss $r$? Because it seems pretty straight forward applying the covariant derivative
And I have similar errors in rotational for example for i=r: (I have used $\sqrt(g)=r$
$$
(rotX)_1=\sqrt(g)\epsilon(1\alpha\beta)g^{\alpha m}\nabla_m X^\beta=r(g^{22}\nabla_2 X^3-g^{33}\nabla_3 X^2)=r(1/r^2\partial_2 X^3-\partial_3 X^2)=1/r\partial_2 X^3-r\partial_3 X^2
$$
Where it should be just $\partial_3 X^2$
Which is my error? Sorry for the levi civita symbol notation but I'm having troubles in sub index

Your divergence formula is correct when you worked (as you probably did) in the coordinate basis ${\partial_1,\partial_2,\partial_2},.$ You obtain the term $\partial_2X^2/r$ by switching to the orthonormal basis ${\partial_1,\partial_2/r,\partial_3}$ where $X^2$ is scaled by $1/r,,$ that is: it is another $X^2,.$ See this post for details. In rot$X$ I think the same thing happens. Another question: why is there the factor $(-1)^{d-1},?$
